# Missing required field in Magento 2 checkout process

Tags: magento2, php

I am using Magento 2.1.8 and I am experiencing an issue where a required field in the checkout process is sometimes not appearing. The field in question is called "Comuna". The field header is displayed, but the field itself is missing, making it impossible to continue with the checkout process.

This issue happens approximately once in every 20 checkout attempts. I have verified that the "Comuna" field is configured correctly in the Magento backend and marked as required. I have also tried checking in different browsers and devices, but the problem persists.

I have checked the Magento error logs but I haven't found any relevant entries. I suspect that this could be a conflict with a third-party module, but I am not sure how to isolate the problem.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.[image]